# Equivalent concept in pandas to R 'frequency()' command?

Tags: pandas, time-series

In R, I can determine the frequency of a dataframe using the `frequency()` command, e.g.

```
myts = ts(x[1:240], frequency = 12)
frequency(myts)
> 12
```

As per the docs:

> `frequency` returns the number of samples per unit time and deltat the time interval between observations (see ts).

Is there a similar concept for verifying pandas timeseries dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only works with `datetime` or `timedelta`, but you can use [`pd.infer_freq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.infer_freq.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=10, freq='13.2min'))
pd.infer_freq(df.index)
#'792S'

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.timedelta_range(start='00:00:00', freq='1H', periods=20))
pd.infer_freq(df.index)
#'H'
```